# To pick one file at a time and move

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

I have two subs mentioned below.

The first sub gets the file modified dates and it is working.

The second sub moves files from one folder to another. Is it possible to merge these 2 subs together so that it first finds the oldest modified time and then moves it accordingly?

however, please also help to include a loop in it.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim fol As Object
    Dim fil As Object
    Dim temp As Date

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fol = FSO.GetFolder("E:\Source")

    For Each fil In fol.Files
        temp = fil.DateLastModified
    Next fil
    MsgBox temp
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub FSOMoveAllFiles()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileInFromFolder As Object

    FromPath = "E:\Source\"
    ToPath = "E:\Destination\"
   
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each FileInFromFolder In FSO.GetFolder(FromPath).Files
        FileInFromFolder.Move ToPath
    Next FileInFromFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: Please have a look on the [File object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object), you already using. by evaluating _DateCreated_ or _DateLastModified_ you could decide which file has to be moved.

Comment: Dear @Brax i have tried but cannot add it

Comment: Sub ShowFileInfo(filespec)
    Dim fs, f, s
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(filespec)
    s = "Created: " & f.DateCreated
    MsgBox s
End Sub

Comment: this is showing error when i am merging both codes

Comment: Please show your modified code. Do you have an idea to finde the oldest file? e.g. `MsgBox FileInFromFolder.DateCreated ` should show you the date

Comment: You can edit your question by hitting the "Edit" button beneath the tags of your question. Please add the texts of your previous two comments to your question, where they belong. Then, delete the two comments. When you move the cursor over your comments, a `Delete` button appears at the end of the comment.

Comment: Dear @TomBrunberg as suggested by i have reviewed the FileObject as suggested by him but it shows errors and i am not able to do it properly, therefore i have merged both codes and are now requesting if anyone of you could please fix it so that it should move 1 file at a time and oldest one should move first, the code should read the time itself as when it arrives in the source folder

Comment: @SalmanShafi Please analyze code before merging them. Have you read the error message? Have you checked if all variables assigned or values set (what is _filespec_ in your code?)? E.g. analyze https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55573789/finding-the-oldest-and-newest-file-in-a-directory for a solution to get oldest file in a folder.

Comment: Dear @Shrotter let me check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next function, able to return the oldest file (according to its creation time):

```
Function OldestFile(strFold As String) As String
 Dim FSO As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object, oldF As String
 Dim lastFile As Date: lastFile = Now

   Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(strFold)
   For Each File In Folder.files
        If File.DateCreated < lastFile Then
            lastFile = File.DateCreated: oldF = File.name
        End If
   Next
   OldestFile = oldF
End Function
```

If you need last modified file you should replace `File.DateCreated` with `File.Datelastmodified`.

It should be called from your code in the next way:

```
Sub MoveOldestFile()
    Dim FromPath As String, ToPath As String, fileName As String

    FromPath = "E:\Source\"
    ToPath = "E:\Destination\"
   
    fileName = OldestFile(FromPath)
    If Dir(ToPath & fileName) = "" Then
        Name FromPath & fileName As ToPath & fileName
    Else
        MsgBox "File """ & fileName & """ already moved..."
    End If
End Sub
```

Each time when the above code is run, moves the oldest file to "ToPath" folder.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru It gives the message that "File Already moved" but it actually is not moving the file

Comment: @SalmanShafi Does the file already exist in the destination folder?

Comment: @Salman Shafi This means that the file **already** exists in the folder where you want moving it. What would you like the code doing in such a case? To firstly delete the existing such a file (with the same name)?

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru the Destination folder is empty but this still gives the same message

Comment: @Salman Ups! I made a mistake... Please, use the updated code. Refresh the page (this one) before copying it. In fact, I only deleted the `Not` word before `Dir(ToPath & fileName)`...

Comment: I have opened the new module. then first i have pasted this code Function OldestFile and then i have pasted the second code Sub MoveOldestFile() and run, and even the destination folder is empty it gives the message as "File Already Moved" it actually reads the file name but is not moving.

Comment: Ok let me check it again :)

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru  Genius  It is working perfect. Bundle of thanks. Now based on this same assumption i have another query but i will ask that in another question

Comment: @Salman Glad I could help! If you tag me (here) after placing the new question (place a link, too) and I will be available I will try helping...

Comment: Thank you, i am adding the new question and will tag you and add the link

Comment: Dear FanDuru please see my next question here on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74336421/to-add-two-hours-of-timer-to-move-file-based-on-date-modified