# to add two hours of timer to move file based on date modified

Tags: vba

Some of VBA Experts have helped me a lot and have fixed the code for me which moves one file one at a time but it first moves the oldest file in the folder. However here i have a complex situation which for now not resolving. i.e. I would like to add a timer of two hours i.e. the file should move after two hour.

e.g. If a file named "North_West data" whose modified time is 6:40 PM i would like the code to move it exactly after two hours. Similarly at the next run the next file which has to be moved has filed modified time e.g. 6:50 PM so the VBA code should actually move it exactly after two hours. this means each file should have automatic two hours delay timer in it, i hope i am able to clarify the query.

```
Function OldestFile(strFold As String) As String
    Dim FSO As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object, oldF As String
    Dim lastFile As Date: lastFile = Now
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(strFold)

    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If File.DateLastModified < lastFile Then
            lastFile = File.DateLastModified: oldF = File.Name
        End If
    Next
    OldestFile = oldF
End Function

Sub MoveOldestFile()
    Dim FromPath As String, ToPath As String, fileName As String

    FromPath = "E:\Source\"
    ToPath = "E:\Destination\"

    fileName = OldestFile(FromPath)

    If Dir(ToPath & fileName) = "" Then
        Name FromPath & fileName As ToPath & fileName
    Else
        MsgBox "File """ & fileName & """ already moved..."
    End If
End Sub
```

You can check the previously resolved query here

[Previous query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334166/to-pick-one-file-at-a-time-and-move/74335831?noredirect=1#comment131234406_74335831)

Comment: The best idea is to use a way able to monitor files creation. You can use WMI. The more efficient way (to not slow down Excel) would be to call a VBScript. I am not available now to supply a solution. Please, look [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/monitor-new-files-in-folder.211547/) and try understanding how to proceed. If you will not slove it, I will be available after no less then 2 hours and I can  try helping only after this time period...

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru thank you for this guidance, i will get this check but will reply after some hours as it is night here. but surely i will get back, it will be a very big help as up till now no one could provide a solution. thanks

Comment: How/when is this code run?   Do you close a excel after running it?

Comment: If you run a Sub in a loop (every couple of minutes maybe) using `Application.OnTime` then that code can move any files it finds which are >2 hours old.  The Excel file would need to be kept open, but that's probably the simplest approach.

Comment: The Sheet is open and I just saved the file in Source folder and application.ontime is 1 minute but now i have changed it to 5 min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next way. Basically, it uses a VBScript able to catch file creation event, which sends the created file name and the moment of creation to a workbook which should be open all the time.

1. Create a VBScript and name it "FolderMonitor.vbs". To do that, please copy the next code in an empty Notepad window:

```
Dim oExcel, strWB, nameWB, wb

strWB = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\Folder monitor.xlsm" 'use here the path of the waiting workbook!
nameWB = Left(strWB, InStr(StrReverse(strWB), "\") - 1)
nameWB = Right(strWB, Len(nameWB))

Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks(nameWB)
if wb is nothing then wbscript.quit 'the necessary workbook is not open...

dim strComputer, strDirToMonitor, strTime, objWMIService, colMonitoredEvents, objEventObject, MyFile
strComputer = "."
'# WMI needs two backslashes (\\) as path separator and each of it should be excaped.
'# So, you must use 4 backslashes (\\\\) as path separator!
strDirToMonitor = "C:\\\\test\\\\test" 'use here your path
'# Monitor Above every 10 secs...
strTime = "10"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN " & strTime & " WHERE " _
        & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
            & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
                & "'Win32_Directory.Name=" & Chr(34) & strDirToMonitor & Chr(34) & "'")
 

Do While True
    Set objEventObject = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent()
    Select Case objEventObject.Path_.Class
        Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
            MyFile = StrReverse(objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent)
            ' Get the string to the left of the first \ and reverse it
            MyFile = (StrReverse(Left(MyFile, InStr(MyFile, "\") - 1)))
            MyFile = Mid(MyFile, 1, Len(MyFile) - 1)

             'send the information to the waiting workbook:
             objExcel.Application.Run "'" & strWB & "'!GetMonitorInformation", Array(MyFile,Now)
             ' some other events can be used starting from here...
    End Select
Loop
```

And save it as stated above. But take care to not save it as "FolderMonitor.vbs.txt". In order to avoid that, when saving you should change 'Save as type`from default`Text documents (*.txt)`to`All files (*.*)`!

In order to make the following code working as it is, you should create a folder named  "VBScript" in the folder where the workbook running the code exists and place the above VBScript inside!

2. Copy the next code in a standard module of a `xlsm` workbook. In order to be called by the above script, as it is, **you should name it "Folder monitor.xlsm"**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ourScript As String = "FolderMonitor.vbs"
Private Const fromPath As String = "E:\Source\"

Sub startMonitoring()
    Dim strVBSPath As String
    strVBSPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VBScript\" & ourScript
    TerminateMonintoringScript 'to terminate monitoring script, if running..
    
    Shell "cmd.exe /c """ & strVBSPath & """", 0
End Sub

Sub TerminateMonintoringScript()
    Dim objWMIService As Object, colItems As Object, objItem As Object, Msg As String
      
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", "WQL", 48)

    For Each objItem In colItems
        If objItem.Caption = "wscript.exe" Then
            '// msg Contains the path of the exercutable script and the script name
            On Error Resume Next
              Msg = objItem.CommandLine 'for the case of null
            On Error GoTo 0
            '// If wbscript.exe runs the monitoring script:
            If InStr(1, Msg, ourScript) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Terminate Wscript process..."
                objItem.Terminate 'terminate process
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Set objWMIService = Nothing: Set colItems = Nothing
End Sub

Sub GetMonitorInformation(arr As Variant)
    'call DoSomething Sub after  2 hours (now IT WILL RUN AFTER 1 MINUTE, for testing reasons...)
    'for running after 2 hours you should change "00:01:00" in "02:00:00":
    arr(0) = Replace(arr(0), "'", "''") 'escape simple quote (') character'
    Application.OnTime CDate(arr(1)) + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "'DoSomething """ & CStr(arr(0)) & """'"
    Debug.Print "start " & Now 'just for testing (wait a minute...)
                                                    'finaly, this line should be commented.
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(strFileName As String)
     Const toPath As String = "E:\Destination\"
     If Dir(toPath & strFileName) = "" Then
            Name fromPath & strFileName As toPath & strFileName
            Debug.Print strFileName & " moved from " & fromPath & " to " & toPath 'just for testing...
     Else
            MsgBox "File """ & toPath & strFileName & """ already exists in this location..."
     End If
End Sub
```

a. You firstly should run "startMonitoring" `Sub`. It can be called from the `Workbook_Open` event.

b. Copy files in the monitored folder and check if they are copied as it should. Note that the code as it is move it **after a minute**. It is commented to exactly show what and how it can be changed...

Comment: @Salman Shafi Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/blf6qf) the workbook and the script I used for testing. You should adapt your used paths...

Comment: Dear @ FANEDURU i logged in just to see if anything has happened. And i saw ur solution. Its midnight here. In the morning i will apply and will test. Would like to say thank u ao much

Comment: 1) I have opened the same workbook you have sent in the link
2) In the VBScript i have changed the following path  strWB = "E:\Delta\Folder monitor.xlsm" 'use here the path of the waiting workbook!
3) In the same VBScript i have updated another following path strDirToMonitor = "E:\\\\Delta\\\\Source" 'use here your path 
Then Save the same VBScript and closed it, 
4) Then I open the Editor pane of the same workbook, where actually the code is already saved.

Comment: 5) I have changed the following path  Private Const fromPath As String = "E:\Delta\Source"
      Const toPath As String = "E:\Delta\Destination\"

6) I have also created a folder "VBScript" in the folder E:\Delta
7) Then i press the Run button it asks for macro to be run first i select "Start Monitoring"
however, the file does not move after waiting for more than 5 minutes, can you please guide

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru i have tried multiple times but the file is not moving at all

Comment: @Salman Shafi Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? If so, I would like to connect to your computer. Otherwise, I cannot understand what you wrongly configured... Firstly, did you saved the downloaded workbook **in E:\Delta** path?

Comment: Yes i have saved the Workbook in E:\Delta path

Comment: Would like to ask about this path         strDirToMonitor = "E:\\\\Delta\\\\Source" 'use here your path    is this the source path?

Comment: I can connect AnyDesk after 6 hours from now

Comment: @Salman Shafi `strDirToMonitor = "E:\\\\Delta\\\\Source` looks to be correct. The above solution should control the files creation in this folder (`Source`). When open `Task manager`, click on `Details` tab (the 6th one), click on `Name` to sort ascending, scroll down to processes name starting with `W`. Do you see there `wscript.exe`? Having an icon like a cube with three visible colored faces...

Comment: now i am seeing the Wscript.exe

Comment: @Salman Shafi Try creating a text document in the respective folder and then go to the workbook VBE and press `Ctrl + G` to show `Immediate Window`. Does (after 5 to 10 seconds) the message "start " followed by the current time appear there?

Comment: in the immediate windows it just say "OK" and no current time appears here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249395/discussion-between-faneduru-and-salman-shafi).

Comment: @Salman Shafi Please, click on the above chat link...

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru you are so amazing you have designed a customized code for me for which i am thankful to you

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru The provided code needs some changes please, it shows errors if a file name contains special characters e.g. if a file name has "Apostrophe" or (brackets)  " ( )  ' the code shows error

Comment: @Salman Shafi Well, for Windows the next characters are illegal: `\/:*?"<>|`. So, if you are talking about double quote (`"`) **nothing can be done**. Then, if you are talking about parenthesis (`( )`) the above code must deal with them **without any problem**. The single quote (`'`) is not an illegal character but it is used to separate the `Sub` "DoSomethng" from its argument (file  name). It is the last one, telling to VBA where the combination `Sub` - `Argument` ends. This character is very seldom used in naming a file and I never imagine that it will be used. I will try escaping it...

Comment: @Salman Shafi OK, adapted it. You should copy (and replace existing) only `GetMonitorInformation` `Sub`. Or insert in it the line `arr(0) = Replace(arr(0), "'", "''") 'escape simple quote (') character'`, as you can see above.

Comment: Let me try it thanks

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru i am getting your point (I am sorry though) I am writing the line can you please make the changes and resend, i will be thankful. Please note it is not moving the files that contains ( ) brackets.

Comment: This is the line which you want me to change     Application.OnTime CDate(arr(1)) + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "'DoSomething """ & CStr(arr(0)) & """'"

Comment: @Salman Shafi 1. Like I said, **I already adapted the above code**. 2. I also posted the line to be inserted `arr(0) = Replace(arr(0), "'", "''") 'escape simple quote (') character'`. You can see its position above. I thought that it will be easier for you to learn... 3. I also said that you need to change only existing `GetMonitorInformation` `Sub` with the updated one. Now, can I connect to your computer using AnyDesk? I will show you how it should work, or i will see **why it does not work in case of your installation**, if really this is the case. But I will stop doing what I did yesterday

Comment: Please wait let me just recheck it

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru i am sorry for the trouble, after updating the code it is working perfectly fine

Comment: I will definitely check why it was which i was not getting. what changes made compare to previous code for my learning. Thanks a lot,.

Comment: Let me update my second question which i just posted today for multiple sources to multiple destinations https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74356514/revisions