# Move files from multiple source folders to multiple destination folders with a two hour delay

Tags: excel, vba

The code (the first part of the code is VBScript) and the second part of the code is (in Excel VBA) moves a file from one source folder to one destination folder with a two hour delay (i.e. each file which comes to source folder will upload after a two hour delay).

However I have 15 source folders and 15 destination folders.

One method is to create 15 VBScript files and 15 Excel files that contains the code for each source and destination folder which I believe is not efficient.

I tried to add multiple source and destination folder options in the below code(s).

The below code is VBscript

```
Dim oExcel, strWB, nameWB, wb

strWB = "E:\Delta\Folder monitor.xlsm"

nameWB = Left(strWB, InStr(StrReverse(strWB), "\") - 1)

nameWB = Right(strWB, Len(nameWB))

Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")

Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks(nameWB)

if wb is nothing then wbscript.quit 'the necessary workbook is not open...

dim strComputer, strDirToMonitor, strTime, objWMIService, colMonitoredEvents, objEventObject, MyFile

strComputer = "."

'# WMI needs two backslashes (\\) as path separator and each of it should be excaped.

'# So, you must use 4 backslashes (\\\\) as path separator!

strDirToMonitor = "E:\\\\Delta\\\\Source" 'use here your path

'# Monitor Above every 10 secs...

strTime = "10"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _

    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN " & strTime & " WHERE " _

        & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _

            & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _

                & "'Win32_Directory.Name=" & Chr(34) & strDirToMonitor & Chr(34) & "'")
 

Do While True

    Set objEventObject = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent()

    Select Case objEventObject.Path_.Class
        Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"

            ' msgbox "OK"

            'MsgBox "A new file was just created: " & _
            
            MyFile = StrReverse(objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent)

            '// Get the string to the left of the first \ and reverse it

            MyFile = (StrReverse(Left(MyFile, InStr(MyFile, "\") - 1)))

            MyFile = Mid(MyFile, 1, Len(MyFile) - 1)

             'send the information to the waiting workbook:

             objExcel.Application.Run "'" & strWB & "'!GetMonitorInformation", Array(MyFile,Now)

    End Select

Loop
```

The second code for this purpose should be copied in a standard module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const ourScript As String = "FolderMonitor.vbs"

Private Const fromPath As String = "E:\Delta\Source\"

Sub startMonitoring()

    Dim strVBSPath As String

    strVBSPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VBScript\" & ourScript

    TerminateMonintoringScript 'to terminate monitoring script, if running..
    
    Shell "cmd.exe /c """ & strVBSPath & """", 0

End Sub

Sub TerminateMonintoringScript()

    Dim objWMIService As Object, colItems As Object, objItem As Object, Msg As String
      
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", "WQL", 48)

    For Each objItem In colItems
        If objItem.Caption = "wscript.exe" Then
            '// msg Contains the path of the exercutable script and the script name
            On Error Resume Next
            Msg = objItem.CommandLine 'for the case of null
            On Error GoTo 0
            '// If wbscript.exe runs the monitoring script:
            If InStr(1, Msg, ourScript) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Terminate Wscript process..."
                objItem.Terminate 'terminate process
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Set objWMIService = Nothing: Set colItems = Nothing
End Sub

Sub GetMonitorInformation(arr As Variant)

    'call DoSomething Sub after  2 hours (now IT WILL RUN AFTER 1 MINUTE, for testing reasons...)

    'for running after 2 hours you should change "00:01:00" in "02:00:00":

    arr(0) = Replace(arr(0), "'", "''") 'escape simple quote (') character'

    Application.OnTime CDate(arr(1)) + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "'DoSomething """ & CStr(arr(0)) & """'"

    Debug.Print "start " & Now 'just for testing (wait a minute...)
                                                    'finaly, this line should be commented.

End Sub

Sub DoSomething(strFileName As String)

    Const toPath As String = "E:\Delta\Destination\"

    If Dir(toPath & strFileName) = "" Then
        Name fromPath & strFileName As toPath & strFileName
        Debug.Print strFileName & " moved from " & fromPath & " to " & toPath 'just for testing...
    Else
        MsgBox "File """ & toPath & strFileName & """ already exists in this location..."
    End If
End Sub
```

[Previous Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74336421/to-add-two-hours-of-timer-to-move-file-based-on-date-modified/74339323?noredirect=1#comment131252634_74339323)

Comment: You should mention that the first code is a VBScript, and separate its code, tell us how it is named. Otherwise, people will not understand your question. It only happens I know it from the previous one...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes correct! i have changed my question and updated it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next scenario. It assumes that you will fill the necessary path in an existing Excel sheet. Since, it will take the necessary paths based on a cell selection, it is necessary to name the sheet in discussion as "Folders". In Column A:A you should fill the 'Source' folder path (ending in backslash "") and in B:B, the 'Destination' folder path (also ending in backslash).

1. The proposed solution takes the necessary paths based on your selection in A:A column. The 'Destination' path is extracted based on the selection row.
2. Please, replace the existing string with the next one, adapting the two necessary paths:

```
Dim oExcel, strWB, nameWB, wb

strWB = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\Folder monitor.xlsm" 'use here your workbook path!!!
nameWB = Left(strWB, InStr(StrReverse(strWB), "\") - 1)
nameWB = Right(strWB, Len(nameWB))

Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks(nameWB)
if wb is nothing then wbscript.quit 'the necessary workbook is not open...

dim strComputer, strDirToMonitor, strTime, objWMIService, colMonitoredEvents, objEventObject, MyFile
strComputer = "."
'# WMI needs two backslashes (\\) as path separator and each of it should be excaped.
'# So, you must use 4 backslashes (\\\\) as path separator!
strDirToMonitor = "C:\\\\test\\\\test" 'use here your path !!!

'# Monitor Above every 10 secs...
strTime = "10"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN " & strTime & " WHERE " _
        & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
            & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
                & "'Win32_Directory.Name=" & Chr(34) & strDirToMonitor & Chr(34) & "'")' and " _
               ' & "'Win32_Directory.Name=" & Chr(34) & strDirToMonitor & Chr(34) & "'")
 

Do While True
    Set objEventObject = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent()
    Select Case objEventObject.Path_.Class
        Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
            MyFile = StrReverse(objEventObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent)
            ' Get the string to the left of the first \ and reverse it
            MyFile = (StrReverse(Left(MyFile, InStr(MyFile, "\") - 1)))
            MyFile = Mid(MyFile, 1, Len(MyFile) - 1)

             'send the information to the waiting workbook:
             objExcel.Application.Run "'" & strWB & "'!GetMonitorInformation", Array(MyFile, Now, strDirToMonitor)
    End Select
Loop
```

The adapted script sends also the source path to the waiting workbook...

3. `TerminateMonintoringScript` `Sub` remains exactly as it is.
4. Please, copy the next adapted code instead of existing one, in the used standard module (`TerminateMonintoringScript` included, even not modified):

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ourScript As String = "FolderMonitor.vbs"
Private fromPath As String, toPath As String

Sub startMonitoring()
    Dim strVBSPath As String, actCell As Range, strTxt As String, pos As Long, endP As Long, oldPath As String
    
    Set actCell = ActiveCell
    If actCell.Parent.Name <> "Folders" Then MsgBox "Wrong activated sheet...": Exit Sub
    fromPath = actCell.Value
    If actCell.Column <> 1 Or Dir(fromPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then Exit Sub   'not a valid path in the selected cell
    
     strVBSPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VBScript\" & ourScript
    'change the script necessary "strDirToMonitor" variable path, if the case:__________________________
    strTxt = ReadFile(strVBSPath)
    
    pos = InStr(strTxt, Replace(fromPath, "\", "\\\\"))
    If pos = 0 Then  'if not the correct path already exists
        pos = InStr(strTxt, "strDirToMonitor = """)          'start position of the existing path
        endP = InStr(strTxt, """ 'use here your path")    'end position of the existing path
        'extract existing path:
        oldPath = Mid(strTxt, pos + Len("strDirToMonitor = """), endP - (pos + Len("strDirToMonitor = """)))
        strTxt = Replace(strTxt, oldPath, _
                         Replace(Left(fromPath, Len(fromPath) - 1), "\", "\\\\")) 'replacing existing with the new one
       
        'drop back the updated string in the vbs file:
        Dim iFileNum As Long: iFileNum = FreeFile
        Open strVBSPath For Output As iFileNum
            Print #iFileNum, strTxt
        Close iFileNum
    End If
    '__________________________________________________________________________________________________
   
    TerminateMonintoringScript 'to terminate monitoring script, if running...
    
     Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02") 'to be sure that the next line will load the updated file...
    
    Shell "cmd.exe /c """ & strVBSPath & """", 0 'run the VBScript
End Sub


Function ReadFile(strFile As String) As String 'function to read the vbscript string content
  Dim iTxtFile As Integer
  
  iTxtFile = FreeFile
  Open strFile For Input As iTxtFile
     ReadFile = Input(LOF(iTxtFile), iTxtFile)
  Close iTxtFile
End Function

Sub TerminateMonintoringScript()
    Dim objWMIService As Object, colItems As Object, objItem As Object, Msg As String
      
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", "WQL", 48)

    For Each objItem In colItems
        If objItem.Caption = "wscript.exe" Then
            '// msg Contains the path of the exercutable script and the script name
            On Error Resume Next
              Msg = objItem.CommandLine 'for the case of null
            On Error GoTo 0
            '// If wbscript.exe runs the monitoring script:
            If InStr(1, Msg, ourScript) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Terminate Wscript process..."
                objItem.Terminate 'terminate process
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Set objWMIService = Nothing: Set colItems = Nothing
End Sub

Sub GetMonitorInformation(arr As Variant)
    'call DoSomething Sub after  2 hours (now IT WILL RUN AFTER 1 MINUTE, for testing reasons...)
    'for running after 2 hours you should change "00:01:00" in "02:00:00":
    arr(0) = Replace(arr(0), "'", "''") 'escape simple quote (') character'
    fromPath = Replace(arr(2), "\\\\", "\")
    Dim rngFrom As Range: Set rngFrom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folders").Range("A:A").Find(what:=fromPath)
    toPath = rngFrom.Offset(, 1).Value
    Application.OnTime CDate(arr(1)) + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "'DoSomething """ & fromPath & "\" & CStr(arr(0)) & """, """ & toPath & CStr(arr(0)) & """'"
    Debug.Print Now; " start " & arr(0) & fromPath & "\" & CStr(arr(0))  'just for testing (wait a minute...)
                                                    'finaly, this line should be commented.
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(sourceFileName As String, destFilename As String)
     If Dir(destFilename) = "" Then
            Name sourceFileName As destFilename
            Debug.Print sourceFileName & " moved to " & destFilename 'just for testing...
     Else
            Debug.Print "File """ & destFilename & """ already exists in this location..."
     End If
End Sub


Sub DoSomething_(strFileName As String) 'cancelled
     If Dir(toPath & strFileName) = "" Then
            Name fromPath & strFileName As toPath & strFileName
            Debug.Print strFileName & " moved from " & fromPath & " to " & toPath 'just for testing...
     Else
            MsgBox "File """ & toPath & strFileName & """ already exists in this location..."
     End If
End Sub
```

So, you only need to replace the existing VBA code with the above adapted one, to place the 'source'/'destination' paths in columns A:B of one of Excel sheets, which to be named "Folders".

Select **in column A:A** a 'Source' cell and run `startMonitoring`.

Play with files creation and check their moving from the new 'source' to the new 'destination'...

But **you have to understand that only a session of the WMI class can run at a specific moment**. This means that **you cannot simultaneously monitor more than one folder**...

I am still documenting regarding the possibility to use a query able to be common for multiple folders. But I never could see such an approach till now and it may not be possible...